# Generating a random image with PHP

Tags: php

OK, so I have a site I'm working on and need two images displayed on the page that are random. I'm running XAMPP to test it locally before it goes live. The image bank is stored in an 'images' folder in the root. The code I'm using is:

```
<img src="images/image<?php echo rand(1,9)); ?>.jpg" />
```

All my images follow the naming convention of image*n*.jpg where n is incremented through the file names. As far as I'm aware, I see no reason for this code not to generate a random image on the page. All I get is a broken link image.

EDIT: Missed the closing quotation mark for the src tag. The code does have this and it doesn't work with it.

Comment: End quote of img-tag is missing.

Comment: Look on the generated page source and tell us what the php is generating.  You should be able to see if a number is being generated, or if you're getting an unexpected output.  Telling us that it only displays a broken image does not give anyone enough information to go off of.  Thanks.

Comment: syntax error: extra round bracket after rand(1,9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also may want to use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) as it is more random then [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and will give you more of a chance that the images wont be repeated.

`<img src="./images/image<?=mt_rand(1,9);?>.jpg" />`

If you have a broken image then view the page source and the correct path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing quotation mark for `src` and you have an extra closing parenthesis. Here is the corrected code:

```
<img src="images/image<?php echo rand(1,9); ?>.jpg" />
```

Comment: Fixed in the EDIT. The original code did have that in and it doesn't work with it. It was a typo.

Comment: Okay. Did you check the source of your page? Can you access the image in `www.yoursite.com/images/image1.jpg`?

Comment: Yes. When I change the code to <img src="images/image1.jpg" /> it works fine.

Comment: Its this `))` you have 2 when it should just be 1

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$imagename = "image" . rand(1, 9) . ".jpg";

<img src="images/<?php echo $imagename; ?>" />
```